# Text View on click listener

Tags: android

I have three text view on page and each of them has on click method. when I click on each of them,Text view3 is called. what is wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.card.admin.nfcapp.ReadCertificateActivity"
android:id="@+id/Test">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dipcert1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="@string/cert1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="200dp"
    android:onClick="btnClickListener1 />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dipcert2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="@string/cert2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
    android:onClick="btnClickListener2 "/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dipcert3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="@string/cert3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="btnClickListener3"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and when I click aon each of them "btnClickListener3" is called.

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Post your java code

Comment: Paste your java code here.

Comment: show screen shot of layout. your textview1 and textview2 is below textview3 .  So you can only click textview3

Comment: my problem is solved.thank you for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three `Textview` has same **layout_width="fill_parent"** and **layout_height="fill_parent"** in `RelativeLayout` so it detect click on only textview3.

Use `LinearLayout` with **orientation="vertical"**.

And set **layout_width="wrap_content"** and **layout_height="wrap_content"** to all `Textview`.

Also as answered by **@aleksandrbel** Remove last space from the name of functions in textview 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot.you saves my time

Answer (score 1):

Take away **space** after the name of functions 1 and 2

```
 android:onClick="btnClickListener1"
```

and

```
 android:onClick="btnClickListener2"
```

But for the purposes if the TextView should do the functionality of the Button, so the user need to know that that he can click it, Material Design suggest to use of cause Buttons.

https://material.google.com/components/buttons.html#

You can just take away the background, if you want to have transparent background

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```